# How to show there exists an infinite sequence satisfying $a_0 = x$ and $(a_n,a_{n+1}) \in R$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Intuitively, we can use the fact that

(i) for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a < b$

in order to conclude that

(ii) there exists an infinite sequence $a : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

1. $a_0 = \sqrt{2}$, and
2. For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $a_n < a_{n+1}$.

Of course, this is easily proved by constructing an explicit example. Like, we could just offer $a_n = \sqrt{2}+n$ as witness. But the point is, even without giving an explicit example, we can deduce (ii) from (i). This works by appealing to the following theorem.

**Proposition 1**. For all sets $X$, all $x \in X$ and any relation $R \subseteq X^2$ that is left-total on $X$, there exists a sequence $a : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$ such that $a_0 = x$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $(a_n,a_{n+1}) \in R.$

I could use a hand proving this proposition. Help, anyone?

*Thoughts*. We can define a new sequence $b : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$ such that

- $b_0 = \{(x)\}$
- $b_{n+1} = \{\tilde{x} \oplus (y) \mid \tilde{x} \in b_n, y \in X, (\tilde{x}_{n},y) \in R\}.$

Where $\oplus$ denotes concatenation. But, where to go from there?

Comment: By *left-total on* $X$ do you mean that $\operatorname{dom}R=X$?

Comment: @BrianMScott, yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a straightforward recursive construction. For each $y\in X$ there is an $f(y)\in X$ such that $\langle y,f(y)\rangle\in R$. Let $b(0)=x$, and for $n\in\Bbb N$ let $b(n+1)=f\big(b(n)\big)$.

Of course in general this uses (part of) the axiom of choice, since $f$ is a choice function for some of the subsets of $X$. In fact the proposition is precisely the statement of the [*axiom of dependent choice*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice), which is strictly weaker than the axiom of choice but still independent of the axioms of $\mathsf{ZF}$.

Comment: This is not precisely DC. It is a slightly stronger formulation of DC which allows us to specify the starting element. DC generally just guarantees that a sequence exists. But these two formulations are indeed equivalent (and I recall a question on the site about that equivalence).

Comment: @Asaf: I’ve actually seen DC defined this way, though I don’t offhand remember where. But you’re right: it’s not the usual formulation.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284461/proving-dependent-choice-with-initial-value-from-dependent-choice-without

Comment: @Asaf: Excellent! Saves me having to write it down (even if it is a fairly obvious gimmick).

Comment: @AsafKaragila, BrianMScott, thanks for the info!!

Comment: @user18921: You’re welcome!